# How to import a typescript class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is how I import **app.config.ts** class in typescript and use it. How do I import the same `AppConfig` class in  Javascript file (config.js) and access the method `getConfig`?

**service.ts**

```
import { AppConfig } from '../app.config';
constructor(private http: Http, private config: AppConfig) {
    this.dataURL = this.config.getConfig('restApi') + '/api/getdata/'
    console.log(this.dataURL)
}
```

Comment: please could you share more info about your current bundler (webpack? ) and specific config ?

Comment: Not at all, because Typescript cannot be directly executed by Javascript. You must have some tooling that takes care of converting Typescript to executable Javascript, the answer lies there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you are asking, so I've split it into to parts:

## If you are trying to import a Typescript file into a JavaScript file

The best solution would be to rename your config.js to config.ts and treat it like a typescript file.

i.e. if you have this:

```ts
export class AppConfig {
  foo: string;
  bar: number;
}
```

And in your config.js you have this:

```ts
export const Config = {
  foo: 'Hello World',
  bar: 42
}
```

but I assume you want something akin to:

```ts
import { AppConfig } from './app.config'

export const Config: AppConfig = {
  foo: 'Hello World',
  bar: 42
}
```

Then just rename config.js to config.ts. It has to be a typescript file for type checking anyways (unless you put the allowJs rule in the tsconfig.json, but even then I don't think it's smart to import .ts files into .js files).

## If you are trying to import a Javascript file (or something) dynamically from your URL

Importing JavaScript files dynamically doesn't actually work in the browser for a couple of technical reasons, not the least of which is security, but also because ES6's "import" (or node's "require") is not in the browser standard.

Instead, I recommend you convert your config to a `JSON` file and use JavaScript's native `JSON.parse` to parse it. I.E:

```ts
http.get(this.dataUrl).toPromise().then(response => {
  let config = null;
  try {
    config = JSON.parse(response.data);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error("Couldn't parse response!");
  }
  this.config = new AppConfig(config); // See note
}
```

Or something along those lines.

**Note:** I assume you have both a copy and a default constructor for your AppConfig class. If you don't, then you can create one, create a parse-function or something akin to that.